# Permission Issue on Bulk Insert in Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

User is getting below error while running bulk insert command in Azure SQL Server. I am using Azure SQL Server and not SQL Sever. Most of the commands related to Bulk Insert grant permission is not working in Azure SQL Server.

**Error**

```
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
```

**Commands Tried in Azure SQL Server to Add User**

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'testuser'; 

ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER testuser

GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO testuser
```

**Error**

```
Msg 40520, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database, grant `ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS` to the principal in the context of the desire database:

```
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO testuser;
```

The user will also need `INSERT` permissions on the target table. These Azure SQL Database permissions are detailed in the [BULK INSERT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) under the permissions section.

Comment: Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Answer (score 2):

On Azure it works on tables in the database in question only.  It does not work on temp tables.  So if you are bulk loading in parallel and want to use temp tables, you are in a corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT CONTROL to testuser
```

nothing else is needed, just this to be executed in content DB (not master)

**full steps**

in Master

```
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='1231!#ASDF!a';
```

in content DB

```
CREATE USER user1 FROM LOGIN login1;

GRANT CONTROL to user1; --(this is for bulk to work)
```