# does Write-SqlTableData need admin permissions?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

The powershell cmdlet [Write-SqlTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata) is erroring for me, if I run it as a user with [db_datawriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=azuresqldb-current) permissions; but I'd have thought that would be enough. If I use the sa account, it works.
Is there some deliberate reason why an ordinary user with db_datareader and db_datawriter cannot be used for this command?

In my powershell script, I'm printing the credentials object and parameter object before calling Write-SqlTableData with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), to help debug. Here is the output in the version where it fails:

> ```
> UserName                                              Password
> --------                                              --------
> apitest1_EngageAI1_import_login01 System.Security.SecureString
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> Credential                     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
> SchemaName                     dbo
> TableName                      AppInsights
> ServerInstance                 REDACTEDserver1.database.windows.net,1433
> InputData                      {@{timestamp=04/01/2024 23:47:12; customer=apitest1; user_Id=a9fa9bf9-33c6-4e3d-ac27-49…
> DatabaseName                   EngageAI1
>
> ##[error]Failed to connect to server REDACTEDserver.database.windows.net,1433.
> ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
> ```

Comment: If I remember correctly, powershell account must have bulk insert privileges

Comment: Are you using the `-Force` parameter? db_ddladmin or ALTER permission of the affected table might be needed as well.

Comment: Not using the -Force parameter, no.

Comment: Update: I've tried adding bulk insert privileges ([GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54836394/174843)), and I've tried adding the [db_ddladmin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=azuresqldb-current), but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Update: even the db_owner role doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the similar issue. the issue is because the use is not present in master database of azure sql.

To resolve this issue, follow below queries to create users:

```sql
-- master databse
CREATE LOGIN myadmin WITH PASSWORD = '<some password>' 
CREATE USER myadmin FOR LOGIN myadmin
```

For each database on the server

```sql
CREATE USER myadmin FROM LOGIN myadmin
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'myadmin'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'myadmin'
```

Use below PowerShell script to write data in table:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your SQL Auth credentials"
$cred.Password.MakeReadOnly()

$srv = Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance "server-name.database.windows.net" -Credential $cred

$db = $srv.Databases["database-name"]
$table = $db.Tables["table-name"]

Write-SqlTableData  -InputData (1,4) -InputObject $table

Read-SqlTableData -InputObject $table
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Can I ask further - do you know **why** there needs to be a user in the master database? It's a surprising requirement.